# SonarQube SQL Injection Vulnerability Warning for JdbcTemplate.query with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

I am encountering a SonarQube vulnerability warning in my Spring Boot project. The warning is related to a potential SQL injection vulnerability in a piece of code that uses JdbcTemplate.query to execute a SQL query. Specifically, the warning appears when I have a line like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from service", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Service>(Service.class));
```

I have checked the documentation for `JdbcTemplate` to see if there are any recommendations regarding SQL injection prevention, but I couldn't find specific guidance.

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly what rule is being triggered. From what I see in the example given I would infer it is a false positive since I do not see any way the SQL can be modified by providing certain values.